# TFS 2013 in VS reports no history for a file with multiple commits in Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

**TLDR version:** How do we work around or resolve TFS reporting that a single file has no history, when Git and the Webportal report that it does, and clearing the TFS cache has no effect?

---

**Disclaimer:** I have tried the various methods in numerous StackOverflow posts regarding the clearing of the cache. To date, that has produced no results. I am hoping to find a different perspective on this issue, even if that perspective indicates that I am doing something wrong.

---

Lately, myself and a coworker have been experiencing the following seemingly pseudo-random symptoms:

1. Clone a repository from git, using the git command line tools.
2. In VS2013, right-click on a file, and retrieve its history. Everything works.
3. Right-click on a second file, and TFS behaves in one of two ways:

   1. Display a dialog with the message, "An item with that key has already been added", and then display the message, "No history available for this item" in the History window.
   2. Simply display the History window with the message "No history available for this item."

Note that once this behavior appears for a file in the solution, it continues to appear without relief. We are unable to view history for it in any way through Visual Studio. However, if we go to the Web Portal, we can see the history just fine, and we can see the history for it using normal git commands, such as `git log` and `git diff`.

I've tried clearing the Git cache, using the script shown in [this Visual Studio Forums article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ar-SA/01342f3c-c04e-4e54-8e24-c0669e164334/error-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added?forum=tfsversioncontrol) (note that it is in Arabic, and may require translation).

Clearing the cache had no effect on the issue, even though I extended the script to cover the versions of Visual Studio and TFS that I am using, was not running Visual Studio when I ran it, and restarted the computer afterwards (and before relaunching Visual Studio).

We also tried deleting the local repository and recloning it from scratch. This had no effect, even if it was the first operation after clearing the cache.

I am not running Team Foundation Server Power Tools, so that is not a contributing factor.

I am using the following software:

- Visual Studio 2013 update 4
- TFS Version 12.0.31101.0, which is TFS 2013 Update 4.
- Windows 8.1 64-bit
- Git for Windows 1.9.4

Some team members also access the repository from the commandline from both Windows and Mac.

Comment: @jessehouwing Update 4.

Comment: @jessehouwing Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 12.0.31101.0

Comment: @jessehouwing This issue occurs randomly across a number of git repositories we manage through TFS. However, once it occurs on a given file, it occurs consistently on *that* file.

Comment: I've not seen it before, that why I'm asking. I've pinged a contact at the Microsoft product group to see. His first guess was that it may be a case sensitivity issue.

Comment: That cache is fully unrelated as it is about [tag:tfvc] and it's not being used for Git with TFS or Visual Studio.

Comment: @jessehouwing That would be odd, as the repository is fully managed with either the Visual Studio command line git tools, or TFS itself.

Comment: Visual Studio uses LibGit2 and LibGit2Sharp to access the repo. That's a different technology stack than the commandline uses. The two not being in agreement is certainly possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81193/discussion-between-mike-hofer-and-jessehouwing).

Comment: If you're willing to share the repository directly with Microsoft, the developer that write the piece of code you're having trouble with, would like to debug it directly against your repo.